# Magento 2.2 Command line error after installation

Tags: installation, fatal-error, magento2.2, php-7, command-line

I have installed fresh magento 2.2 which is working fine but command lines are not working.  I am using ubuntu.

Getting strange error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384

Did search but not found any solution. As magento 2.2 is successfully installed so it fulfilled all required settings which magento 2.2 required.  What could be the issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ jack, did you run the setup upgrade command after the installation ?

Comment: no i didn't run setup updgrade command.  After installation i tried to disable the cache so did hit the cache command and got that error

Comment: Just now i have run the upgrade command still giving that error.  Need expert advice why am i having this issue?  is there any solution of this problem in world?

Comment: Make sure you have provided proper permission to the pub/static, generated, and var folder. Double check, your generated folder have write permission. After that, run the following commands,
php bin/magento setup: upgrade and after that, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 2):

You need to install all php module as per required of Magento2.
    For this error it seems you have not installed php-xml module.

**So install module by below command**

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

**There is a list of module that you will need to install before Magento2 installation**

```
   PDO/MySQL
   mbstring
   mcrypt
   mhash
   curl
   gd2
   soap
   simplexml
```

**For PHP 7 run below commands**

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-curl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-openssl php7.0-zip php7.0-soap

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have already installed php-xml  module and restarted apache but still showing same error wh?

Comment: let me know php-version?

Comment: PHP version is 7.0.2

Comment: check updated answer and run commands for php 7

Comment: As magento 2.2 already installed so all required php modules are already there.    Is there anything you can figure out?

Comment: Since your issue is' DOMDocument' hence thats belongs to DOM module,make sure this is installed as per your php version and this is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

use php -v to check you version of php, 
you need php-7.0 instead of 7.2, if you are using php 7.2 you need to remove the 
package with apt-get remove php7.2-common --purge

then reinstall php7.0 dependencies; hopefully this could fix your issue